# Using PHP to convert Bitcoin Private Key but get wrong SHA256?

Tags: php, sha256, bitcoin

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format

Trying to follow this example here to do this in PHP, but I get stuck at step 3.

I can't seem to get the same SHA256 hash.

I take the extended key from step 2 `800C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D`

and SHA256 it.

I should get `8147786C4D15106333BF278D71DADAF1079EF2D2440A4DDE37D747DED5403592` according to step 3 but I just get `E2E4146A36E9C455CF95A4F259F162C353CD419CC3FD0E69AE36D7D1B6CD2C09`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And the code you are using is ... where?

Comment: We can't tell you what you are doing wrong until you tell us what you are doing.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the code is. I can go to webpage sha256 hashing tools and enter the extended key into it and it still gives me the unexpected output. But for the sake of it, `hash('sha256', $extendedkey);`

Comment: it does if you want to ask a question on S.O

Comment: No, it doesn't, because it's certainly not a problem with the code; i'm certain that all these different websites can't have messed up sha256.

Comment: if its not a code problem, then why are you asking here?

Comment: You're just all sorts of elitist and unhelpful, aren't you?

Comment: Rob, it does matter mainly because you could be making a simple mistake that we will catch. We are not about to go and try and recreate this "fluke" on our own when you cannot be arsed to provide us with your (non-)working code. You are the one who wants help, so help the ones who WANT to help you.

Comment: you obstinacy over it, not being a code issue, makes it impossible to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are hashing the literal string

```
"800C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D"
```

This is not what what needs to happen.  This is a string of bytes.  It's in HEX format just to make viewing it easier.  In reality, this represents a binary string.  That's what you need to be hashing.

[`hex2bin`](http://php.net/hex2bin) is your friend here.

```
<?php
$hex = '800C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D';
echo hash('sha256', hex2bin($hex));
```

DEMO: https://eval.in/69440

Another example:

```
<?php
$key = '0C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D';
$binKey = hex2bin($key);

$binKey = hex2bin(80).$binKey;

echo hash('sha256', $binKey);
```

DEMO: https://eval.in/69443

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense and yup, this works as expected. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working PHP-code example:

```
<?php

//EXAMPLE INPUT: 0C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D
//EXAMPLE OUTPUT: 5HueCGU8rMjxEXxiPuD5BDku4MkFqeZyd4dZ1jvhTVqvbTLvyTJ
//see https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format for more info

function decodeHex($hex)
{
    $hex = strtoupper($hex);
    $chars = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    $return = '0';
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($hex); $i++)
    {
        $current = (string)strpos($chars, $hex[$i]);
        $return = (string)bcmul($return, '16', 0);
        $return = (string)bcadd($return, $current, 0);
    }
    return $return;
}

function encodeBase58($hex)
{
    $orighex = $hex;
    $chars = '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $hex = decodeHex($hex);
    $return = '';
    while(bccomp($hex, 0) == 1)
    {
        $dv = (string)bcdiv($hex, '58', 0);
        $rem = (integer)bcmod($hex, '58');
        $hex = $dv;
        $return = $return.$chars[$rem];
    }
    $return = strrev($return);

    //leading zeros
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($orighex) && substr($orighex, $i, 2) == '00'; $i += 2)
    {
        $return = '1' . $return;
    }

    return $return;
}

if(!isset($_SERVER['argv'][1]))
{
    exit("Usage: php convert_bitcoin_private_key_to_wif_format.php private_key\n");
}

$privateKey = $_SERVER['argv'][1];

//add a 0x80 byte in front of it 
$buffer = '80' . $privateKey; 
$extendedKey = $buffer;

//perform SHA-256 hash on the extended key 
$buffer = strtoupper(hash('sha256', hex2bin($buffer)));

//perform SHA-256 hash on result of SHA-256 hash 
$buffer = strtoupper(hash('sha256', hex2bin($buffer)));

//take the first 4 bytes of the second SHA-256 hash, this is the checksum 
$checksum = substr($buffer, 0, 8);

//add the checksum at the end of the extended key
$buffer = $extendedKey . $checksum;

//convert the result from a byte string into a base58 string
$buffer = encodeBase58($buffer);

echo($buffer . "\n");

?>
```